# How to merge multiple line items with duplicates into single line in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a csv file that is '|' delimited and has multiple lines in it. Some entries in the file have duplicates and I need to merge these entries into a single line. These entries will then be used to create a map object. I am new to java and need help on how to do this.. I created a map object but don't know how to handle the duplicates. Can anyone suggest how to do this in java?

My list:

```
HR |325|50051710|CN=ADGroup1

HR |325|50051710|CN=ADGroup2

BA |375|50110084|CN=ADGroup1

SYS ADMIN |877|50145471|CN=ADGroup2
```

Output has to be like this to be read as map object:

```
HR |325|50051710|CN=ADGroup1,CN=ADGroup2

BA |375|50110084|CN=ADGroup1
...
```

My code:

```
     Map attrList = new HashMap();
     String[] record = line.split("\\|");
     try{
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            if (record[1] != null  ) {
                Map map = new HashMap();
                String costcentre = record[1].trim();
                map.put("Costcentre", costcentre);
                String jobcode = record[2].trim();
                map.put("Jobcode", jobcode);
                String adgroup = record[3].trim();
                map.put("ADGroup", adgroup);
                attrList.put(costcentre + jobcode, map);
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code at the moment? Do you get errors, or does it not work? What have you tried so far? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: How do I read the duplicate and add it to the map?

Answer (score 0):

I made this code and I believe it solves your problem (let me know if it really does):

{

```
    String tempString, group;
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<String> myList; 

    myList = createListFromFile("myFile.txt");      

    for(String string : myList){
        tempString = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf('|'));
        group = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('|'), string.length());
        if(myMap.containsKey(tempString)){
            //substring is used here to remove '|' character
            myMap.put(tempString, myMap.get(tempString) +","+group.substring(1, group.length()));
        }else{
            myMap.put(tempString, tempString + group);
        }
    }

    //For testing
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key = "+entry.getKey()); 
        System.out.println("value = "+entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static List<String> createListFromFile(String path){

    //you might need to change the Charset
    Charset charsetUTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), charsetUTF8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
```

}

Comment: When I try to compile, I see this : The method get(String) is undefined for the type Paths